# Call method as soon as eclipse plug-in starts

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I'm developing a plug-in for Eclipse Luna and I wanted to add some listeners to some view and I know how to do it. My question is where to do it?

I need them to be added as soon as the plug-in starts. So I'm thinking there must be some kind of method that gets called when the plug-in is loaded I just can't find it in docs. So far I tried adding this listeners in `public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception` method in `Activator` class but it didn't work. I think that the ui part is not still loaded at that point and that's why it's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plug-in's Activator `start` method is not run until something else in the plug-in is used so this is not a suitable place to put listeners. By default plug-ins are not loaded during Eclipse initialization, they are only loaded when needed.

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to define a class implementing `IStartup` that will be run during Eclipse initialization.

Note that the `earlyStartup` method defined by this interface may be run before the UI is initialized. Use something like the following to run UI code from `earlyStartup`:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
     // UI code
  }
});
```

For example to get the selection service:

```java
@Override
public void earlyStartup()
{
  Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     final ISelectionService service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();
     System.out.println("service " + service);
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: I tried to call PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService(); to get the selection service but it throws NPE.

Comment: That works as long as you do all of it in the asyncExec Runnable - see my additional example in the answer.

Comment: It didn't work for me so I just created UIJob, put everything in its run method and scheduled it.